# Draw a resizable rectangle in the panel on clicking the button

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, resizable

I'm new to java swing. I'm trying to draw a resizable rectangle in the panel as if I clicked on a red button it should draw a resizable rectangle in the red panel, same for the green button and blue button but the action listener works and the shape didn't show in the panel

**Following is a resizable component class**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;


// it is resizable component code

class ResizableComponent extends JPanel {

    private int SIZE = 8;
    private Rectangle2D[] points = {new Rectangle2D.Double(50, 50, SIZE, SIZE), new Rectangle2D.Double(150, 100, SIZE, SIZE)};
    Rectangle2D s = new Rectangle2D.Double();
    ShapeResizeHandler ada = new ShapeResizeHandler();

    public ResizableComponent() {
        addMouseListener(ada);
        addMouseMotionListener(ada);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            g2.fill(points[i]);
        }
        s.setRect(points[0].getCenterX(), points[0].getCenterY(),
                Math.abs(points[1].getCenterX() - points[0].getCenterX()),
                Math.abs(points[1].getCenterY() - points[0].getCenterY()));

        g2.draw(s);
    }

    class ShapeResizeHandler extends MouseAdapter {

        Rectangle2D r = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, SIZE, SIZE);
        private int pos = -1;

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
            Point p = event.getPoint();

            for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
                if (points[i].contains(p)) {
                    pos = i;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
            pos = -1;
        }

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
            if (pos == -1) {
                return;
            }

            points[pos].setRect(event.getPoint().x, event.getPoint().y, points[pos].getWidth(),
                    points[pos].getHeight());
            System.out.println("x : " + event.getPoint().x);
            System.out.println("y : " + event.getPoint().y);
            System.out.println("w : " + points[pos].getWidth());
            System.out.println("h : " + points[pos].getHeight());
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

**And following is the Drawing class to draw frame and panels**

```
public class Drawing extends JFrame{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Drawing d= new Drawing();

        d.setSize(1000,800);
        d.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        d.setVisible(true);
        d.setLayout(null);

        JPanel redPanel = new JPanel();
        redPanel.setBounds(0,0,300,700);
        redPanel.setBackground(Color.red);

        JPanel greenPanel = new JPanel();
        greenPanel.setBounds(300,0,400,700);
        greenPanel.setBackground(Color.green);

        JPanel bluePanel = new JPanel();
        bluePanel.setBounds(700,0,300,700);
        bluePanel.setBackground(Color.blue);

        JPanel yellowPanel = new JPanel();
        yellowPanel.setBounds(0,700,1000,100);
        yellowPanel.setBackground(Color.yellow);

        JTextField tf =new JTextField("Default",30);
        tf.setEditable(false);
        
        JButton redButton = new JButton("red");
        
        JButton greenButton = new JButton("Green");

        JButton blueButton = new JButton("Blue");

        yellowPanel.add(tf);
        yellowPanel.add(redButton);
        yellowPanel.add(greenButton);
        yellowPanel.add(blueButton);

        d.add(redPanel);
        d.add(greenPanel);
        d.add(bluePanel);
        d.add(yellowPanel);

        redButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                redPanel.add(new ResizableComponent());
                redPanel.repaint();
                String s = e.getActionCommand();
                System.out.println(s + " Clicked");
            }
        });

        greenButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                greenPanel.add(new ResizableComponent());
                greenPanel.repaint();
                String s = e.getActionCommand();
                System.out.println(s + " Clicked");
            }
        });

        blueButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                bluePanel.add(new ResizableComponent());
                bluePanel.repaint();
                String s = e.getActionCommand();
                System.out.println(s + " Clicked");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `d.setSize(1000,800);` and `d.setVisible(true);` should be the last two lines in method `main` in class `Drawing`. Also, after you add components to a container, you need to call method [revalidate()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#revalidate--) before calling method `repaint()`.

Comment: Also, when creating your ResizableComponent you need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method so your component can be displayed properly.

Comment: What is your GUI supposed to be doing?

Comment: @Abra that works. Thank you so much. I want to know something more as the resizable component added in the panel as a separate component as shown in the pic at [link]https://github.com/amjadashfaq/image/blob/main/image.png . Is it possible to make that resizable rectangle a part of that red panel so it will be drawn on red panel?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I'm coding a component that will get the different color sequence of objects (that I'll add later) that lie in the boundary of the rectangle so I want to make that resizable rectangle to be a part red panel instead of a separate component. Is it possible?

Comment: I still don't understand what your GUI is supposed to be doing.  Please explain it step by step.

Comment: *I want to make that resizable rectangle to be a part red panel instead of a separate component* - anything is possible, it is a matter of difficulty. Mouse events are only dispatched to a component. So it is easy to listen for an even on a component and drag it or resize it. If you paint objects on a panel, then only the panel receives the event so you need extra logic to determine which "graphic" you want to drag or resize.

Comment: @camickr Thank you so much for the help, The problem solved.